# Multiple pagers in single page

Tags: paging

Hi I have a page in which I have added 2 blocks in both blocks I have paging,but when ever i click any page number of either a block both the page change simultaneously in Drupal7

$output .= theme('pager', array('tags' => array()));
This is generating pager.

Pls help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `element` parameter:

> An optional integer to distinguish between multiple pagers on one page.

e.g.

First call:

```
$output .= theme('pager', array('tags' => array(), 'element' => 0));
```

Second call:

```
$output .= theme('pager', array('tags' => array(), 'element' => 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented the multipage on a single page in **Drupal 8**
Note:-  The $element value is the key here. It should be same for both query extend and pager element.

**100% working solution.** Please find the exact solution for the same below:-

```
public function multiplePagers() {
    $build['pager_table_0'] = $this->buildTestTable(0);
    $build['pager_pager_0'] = $this->getPagerElement(0);

    $build['pager_table_1'] = $this->buildTestTable(1);
    $build['pager_pager_1'] = $this->getPagerElement(1);

    $build['pager_table_2'] = $this->buildTestTable(2);
    $build['pager_pager_2'] = $this->getPagerElement(2);

    $build['pager_table_3'] = $this->buildTestTable(3);
    $build['pager_pager_3'] = $this->getPagerElement(3);


    //render your table and pager respectively in you template 
    return [
        '#theme' => 'your_theme_name',
        '#data' => $build
    ]
}


public static function getPagerElement($element){
    return [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['test-pager-'.$element]],
        '#use-ajax' => TRUE,
        'pager' => [
            '#type' => 'pager',
            '#element' => $element,
        ],
    ];
}


protected function buildTestTable($element) {
    $header = [
        ['data' => 'wid'],
        ['data' => 'type'],
        ['data' => 'timestamp'],
    ];
    $query = Database::getConnection()->select('watchdog', 'd')->extend(PagerSelectExtender::class)->element($element);
    $result = $query
        ->fields('d', ['wid', 'type', 'timestamp'])
        ->limit(20)
        ->orderBy('d.wid')
        ->execute();
    $rows = [];
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[] = ['data' => (array) $row];
    }
    return [
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#empty' => $this->t("There are no watchdog records found in the db"),
    ];
}
```

Feel free to thank me later :-)